# Cutting off a chunk from the north

Tags: internal-consistency, planets, earth-like, worldbuilding-process

I want to make a map of a completely made-up world; the main issue is the island of the elves.

According to their history, a piece of land floated away from the north, and then the "water people" sank it: the island descended into the ocean, where a magic barrier prevents the ocean from overflowing it. It is therefore like an island resting at the bottom of the sea, a hole surrounded by big water walls, with one mountain or hill (I haven't decided which).

One can always add a magical myth to the story, but I wanna take a geographic approach. What I am wondering is: **is it geologically possible for a mass to break away and drift from the northern region and towards the south?** I am only asking about the drift of the land from north to south, not how it sunk to the sea-bed.

Yes, I have a million years to spare. Also, the piece of the land is smaller than Australia but looks *almost* like it.

Comment: This needs a lot of clarification. Geography isn't plants and animals, not sure what you mean by "water bed", what smoothness has to do with anything, or what 'geographic' drift is.

Comment: [Land masses drift all the time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_drift). Very slowly -- the speed is measured in centimeters or inches per year. And even at this extremely slow speed they have tremendous kinetic energy... The question is, do you have a hundred million years to spend waiting? (And when you say "this map" people do expect you to show the map. If you don't want to show the map, keep it generic and say "a map".)

Comment: @rek when I said geography and put parenthesis around plant and animals, I meant, apart from these two everything is similar to earth. When I said about drift and smoothness...you need to see a world map.

Comment: @AlexP I haven't made the map, I get stuck whenever I try to draw it.

Comment: Your edit and reply haven't cleared up anything.

Comment: Per chance, when you say *"not sunk like Atlantic"*, do you mean the legendary city of "[Atlantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantis)"? In the end, is your question about a mini-continent which slipped away from the north, then was brought down. It has been kept dry by putting away water magically, creating as a consequence a surrounding water wall of the height of the ocean? And your question is about the first two steps (moving, and brought down into water), right?

Comment: @Tortliena my question is about the first half of your answer, I just wanna know if is it possible that such a large piece can separate from the north.

Comment: @Tortliena brought down is 100% magical part, I want to know about the moving part.

Comment: @Momobear I've reshaped quite a lot your question to better reflect what you are asking. I've notably reordered some parts so that descriptions and the question are better divided. Please don't hesitate to tell and edit if something's amiss to you. It's your question after all :).

Comment: Added further clarification, but this question seems to be asking if it's possible for continents to break up and drift apart. Which, I mean, *yes?*

Comment: @Tortliena yes that seems much better now. Thanks for the edits!

Comment: @rek I am aware of the continents drifting apart, but can a piece, this large, drift from the extreme north? For better imagination, picture another Australia breaking off, this time from Russia. Yes, I have a few million years to spare.

Comment: Australia broke and drifted from Africa, so again, yes. This is just continental drift.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible—geographically—for a piece of mass to drift from the northern region?

Is it theoretically possible that on another world a land mass could drift from one hemisphere to another ?  Yes.  There's just no reason it can't, but such drift is slow and it would take a very long time.

> According to their [elves] history, a piece of land floated away from the north

This is not something any society without near immortality is likely to have a record of.  The timescale for such a process is hundreds of millions of years.  Most *species* won't last that long (the elves would likely be extinct before you need the map) and the idea of historical records surviving that long is extremely unlikely - I think we have at least one Q&A on that subject.

A *myth* might develop that such a thing happened.  Alternatively Elf scientists might *discover* that such continental drift occured and have a reasonable hypothesis that appears to show that the original location was in what is now the southern hemisphere.

> and then the "water people" sunk it.

I have no idea how your sink even a small continent (or even an island).  Any culture capable of this would make darn sure your elves were *all* dead and make a good job of it.  The event itself would make it practically impossible for any records of the prior drift to survive and the survivors would have a heck of a lot more pressing needs that maintaining historical records (for generations to come).

> When we look at the world map, you can see the north is smooth than the south. You get all the mess as you go down, but north is comparatively smooth.

Go tell that to the Alps, Urals, Rockies and the Himilayas.  I have no idea why you think this difference exists.  There's certainly no basis for such a difference in a general sense that all planets would need to have it.